# Why is there a product-recomendation tag if those questions are "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Just noticed this tag today: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation

Should we at least point out that they are off-topic questions in the tag details or delete the tag altogether?  It's very confusing for users to see a tag like this, I think.

Comment: It's specified in the full wiki, but not as obvious as it should be: https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/product-recommendation/info

Comment: @BMitch, Ok, I didn't realize there was a "full wiki" for tags.  I just saw the shorter explanation.

Comment: Indeed, I doubt many look that far, which is why I agree with your suggestions.